# Swift / SpriteKit: evenly distribute SKShapeNodes horizontally and vertically into a grid

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to equally distribute an *n* amount of square `SKShapeNodes` over the screen to create a square grid. I tried searching for other examples of this, but I cannot find the solution I'm looking for as most solutions only focus on only distributing views horizontally.

I'm creating the squares in a for loop, however I can only get them to move on either the x or the y axes, not both. The below example gives me the best result, but as expected from the code only the first two squares are visible, the third one is created off screen:

`amountOfTiles` is a `CGFloat` set to 4

`tile` is an `SKShapeNode`

```
func addTiles() {

    let screenWidth = self.view?.frame.size.width
    tileWidth = screenWidth! / (amountOfTiles / 2)
    tileHeight = tileWidth

    tileX = 0
    tileY = 0

    tileRect = CGRect(x: tileX, y: tileY, width: tileWidth, height: tileHeight)

    for _ in 0...Int(amountOfTiles) {

        tile = SKShapeNode(rect: tileRect)
        tile.position = CGPoint(x: tileX, y: tileY)
        tile.fillColor = .red

        addChild(tile)

        tileX += tileWidth
        tileY += tileHeight
    }
}
```

My guess is that I should not update the Y and X positions of the squares at the same time, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself. I removed `amountOfTiles` and added two separate `CGFloats` for x and y, which I update in a separate loop:

```
func addTiles() {

        let xAmount:CGFloat = 4
        let yAmount:CGFloat = 4

        let screenWidth = self.view?.frame.size.width
        tileWidth = screenWidth! / (xAmount)
        tileHeight = tileWidth

        tileY = 0

        tileRect = CGRect(x: tileX, y: tileY, width: tileWidth, height: tileHeight)

        for _ in 0..<Int(xAmount) {

            tileX = 0

            for _ in 0..<Int(yAmount) {

                tile = SKShapeNode(rect: tileRect)
                tile.fillColor = .red

                addChild(tile)

                tile.position = CGPoint(x: tileX, y: tileY)
                tileX += tileWidth
            }

            tileY += tileHeight
        }
}
```